# fviz_cluster , R studio, Análise de Cluster

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tendo o seguinte script :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(factoextra)
library(ggplot2)


mlb <-  read.csv("C:\\...\\prospects.csv")  
##
##fonte da planilha prospects.csv
##https://www.mlb.com/prospects/stats/top-prospects
##

mlb <-mlb %>% select(15,18)

df=scale(mlb)
head(df, n=3)

# Número ótimo de clusters 

fviz_nbclust(df, kmeans, method = "wss")+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 3, linetype = 2)


# Clusterização k-means
##set.seed(123)
km.res=kmeans(df, 3, nstart=25)
print(km.res)

aggregate(mlb, by=list(cluster=km.res$cluster), mean)

mlb2=cbind(mlb, cluster=km.res$cluster)
head(mlb2)


km.res$centers

fviz_cluster(km.res, data=mlb2,
             palette = c("#2E9FDF", "#00AFBB", "#E7B800"),
             ellipse.type="euclid",
             star.plot=TRUE,
             addlabels=TRUE,
             repel=TRUE,
             ggtheme=theme_minimal()
)

##mapa do gpot
ggplot(mlb2, aes(slg , strikeOuts, colour = cluster)) + 
  geom_point()
```

O gráfico é gerado , mas os dimensões slg , strikeOuts ("avanços" e eliminações) não são nomeadas e são exibidas em percentuais sinalizados (DIM! & DIM2) e não em mapa "real", como o do "gpot".

Creio que minha dúvida talvez seja entender a natureza do gráfico fviz_cluster.

Mas como no fviz_cluster exibir como no ggplot (se isto faz sentido) ?

---

## Edição

O código seguinte baixa a planilha usada. Ver comentários [1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/567573/fviz-cluster-r-studio-an%c3%a1lise-de-cluster?noredirect=1#comment1001357_567573) e [2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/567573/fviz-cluster-r-studio-an%c3%a1lise-de-cluster?noredirect=1#comment1001376_567573) à pergunta.

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(rvest)
  library(tidyverse)
})

link <- "https://www.mlb.com/prospects/stats/top-prospects?type=all&minPA=1"
page <- read_html(link)
tbl_list <- page %>%
  html_elements("table") %>%
  html_table()

mlb <- tbl_list[[1]] %>% select(15, 18)
```

Comment: O problema não pode ser reproduzido. Depois de `mlb %>% select(15,18)` não há variáveis `slg` , `strikeOuts` (antes também não).

Comment: Grato pelo retorno @Rui Barradas , testei no meu R e foi. A planilha está disponível no site informado, mas ela é irrelevante , a dúvida é sobre a fviz_cluster , dim1 e dim2, mas grato assim mesmo.

Comment: Dim1 e Dim 2 têm a ver com análise de componentes principais. A documentação da função `fviz_cluster` podia ser muito mais clara em relação a isso. Internamente  [`fviz_cluster` chama](https://github.com/kassambara/factoextra/blob/master/R/fviz_cluster.R#L177) a função `stats::prcomp` (umas linhas mais abaixo). E formata os nomes dos eixos como dimensões ou componentes principais.

Comment: Ah, eu tinha visto a planilha, obrigado pelo link.

Comment: Grato ,vou ler , e aprendi a baixar a fonte de dados de um site !!